# Restrict API access to specific app clients

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have built an iOS and an Android app. These apps use Cognito User Pools to allow public authenticated and unauthenticated access to API Gateway.

I am trying to prevent third-party apps from accessing this API. I only want apps that I have authorized to have API access. Is possible to limit access to APIG to only my apps?

Cognito provides the notion of an App Client ID and App Client Secret in the settings for the user pool. Is this the preferred mechanism to limit Cognito logins to whitelisted clients/apps? The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-client-apps.html) provide little clarification as to the purpose of this configuration or a best practice for keeping these keys secure in the wild.

Are there alternative methods to achieve what I'm attempting? Is this goal even possible to accomplish? I believe an app could be reverse engineered for these keys or they could be discovered via a network sniffer.

I am a bit of a novice on API security so your insights are appreciated.

Comment: My current work generates a JWT token after login. So all data is dynamic. Of course, if you get user/pass, you are in. Then I am using API Gateway Autorizers which do a lambda call per request (there is cache too). If this validates the (in my case) JTW, method is allowed to pass. Not sure if this can actually help you.

Comment: Are you using Cognito for this? I think the restriction needs to happen at the Cognito level. Only certain apps must be permitted to receive a login token, which then controls APIG access. I hope I’m explaining this right.

Comment: I played with Cognito only a few. If I find something, I will let you know.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you have authenticated access & unauthenticated access to your APIs on API gateway, and you want to limit unauthenticated access to you app only. One way of doing this would be using `API keys` for API gateway, though it's purpose is not for authentication. These `API keys` are static in nature & you would have to implement your own system to rotate these keys. Preferred way would be to use `identity federation` with `user pools` to access your API gateway. I can add more details if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @ASR, please let me clarify. I'd like to limit API access to my "official" app so that only this app (iOS and Android versions) can connect. This would cover authenticated OR unauthenticated roles. I think this would need to be handled at the Cognito tier, by somehow only allowing certain API keys or App Clients through. I am currently using a user pool for auth. The goal is to prevent any non-sanctioned apps from connecting to the API. Any additional implementation details you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Cognito Identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-identity.html). `Cognito Federated Identity Pools` provide for both authenticated & unauthenticated access. This is going to be long, so please bear with me. (my code examples are using cloudformation in yaml or JS). I will assume that you have created your `user pool` & `app client`. You are going to need those to create an `identity pool`. I will also assume that your user pool `allowed oauth flows` is set to `implicit grant` and `allowed oauth scope` is `openid`. This is required to get the `id_token` which is used to create a `federated identity`.

1. create `cognito identity pool` using your `cognito user pool` as an authenticated provider. Sample CFN yaml for the same

   ```
   AccIdenAdminPool:
     Type: "AWS::Cognito::IdentityPool"
         Properties:
           IdentityPoolName: <identity pool name as input>
           AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities: true
           CognitoIdentityProviders: 
             - ClientId: <your app client id>
               ProviderName: "cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<your user pool id>"
               ServerSideTokenCheck: true
   ```
2. Now attach your authenticated & unauthenticated roles to the `identity pool` you just created. Sample JS code -

   ```
   module.exports.attachRole = (event, context, callback) => {

     console.log(JSON.stringify(event));           // successful response

     let params = {
       IdentityPoolId: event.identityPoolId, /* required */
       Roles: {
           /* required */
           'authenticated': <auth role arn>,
           'unauthenticated': <unauth role arn>
       },
     };

     cognitoidentity.setIdentityPoolRoles(params, function (err, data) {
       if (err) {
           console.log(err, err.stack);
       }
       else {
           console.log("success");      // successful response       
       }
     });
   }
   ```
3. Change API gateway authentication from `Cognito user pool authorizer` to `AWS_IAM`. This is a must. If for some reason you cannot do this, you need to figure some other way out to have closed unauthenticated access to you APIs.
4. For authenticated access, use the `id_token` (received after successful login), identity pool id & user pool id to get `CognitoIdentityCredentials`. Sample code -

   ```
   function getAccessToken(idToken, idenPoolId, userPool) {
       let region = idenPoolId.split(":")[0];
       let provider = "cognito-idp." + region + ".amazonaws.com/" + userPool;
       let login = {};

       login[provider] = idToken;

       console.log(provider + ' || ' + idenPoolId);

       // Add the User's Id Token to the Cognito credentials login map.
       let credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
           IdentityPoolId: idenPoolId,
           Logins: login
       });

       //call refresh method in order to authenticate user and get new temp credentials
       credentials.get((error) => {
           if (error) {
               console.error(error);               
           } else {
               console.log('Successfully logged!');
               console.log('AKI:'+ credentials.accessKeyId);
               console.log('AKS:'+ credentials.secretAccessKey);
               console.log('token:' + credentials.sessionToken);
           }
       });
   }
   ```

   Use this `access key,`secret key`and`token` to hit your APIs. It will have permissions based on your authenticated role you provisioned in step 2.
5. For unauthenticated access, login step will obviously be skipped but you can still generate temporary keys for access to your APIs. Sample code is very similar, with one key difference. `Logins` parameter is not required.

   ```
   function getUnauthToken(idenPoolId) {

       console.log(idenPoolId);

       // Add the User's Id Token to the Cognito credentials login map.
       let credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
           IdentityPoolId: idenPoolId,
       });

       credentials.get((error) => {
           if (error) {
               console.error(error);

           } else {
               console.log('Unauth AKI:'+ credentials.accessKeyId);
               console.log('Unauth AKS:'+ credentials.secretAccessKey);
               console.log('Unauth token:' + credentials.sessionToken);                    
           }
       });
   }
   ```

   This set of keys has permissions based on your unauthenticated role as provisioned in step 2.

`Roles` - this is how created roles & it's policy for my API gateway. Example in CFN yaml

```
AuthenticatedRole:
  Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
  Properties:
    RoleName: "AuthenticatedRole"
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        -
          Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
            - "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
          Principal:
            Federated: 
              - "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
          Condition:
            StringEquals: 
              cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud: <your identity pool id>
            ForAnyValue:StringLike:
              cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr: authenticated
    Path: "/"
AuthRolePolicy:
  Type: "AWS::IAM::Policy"
  Properties:
    PolicyName: AuthRolePolicy
    PolicyDocument: 
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement: 
        - 
          Effect: "Allow"
          Action: "execute-api:Invoke"
          Resource:
            - "arn:aws:execute-api:<region>:<account id>:<api id>/*/*/acc/*"]]
    Roles: 
      - 
        Ref: AuthenticatedRole
UnauthRole:
  Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
  Properties:
    RoleName: UnauthRole
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        -
          Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
            - "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
          Principal:
            Federated: 
              - "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
            Condition:
            StringEquals: 
              cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud: <your identity pool id>
    Path: "/"
UnauthRolePolicy:
  Type: "AWS::IAM::Policy"
  Properties:
    PolicyName: UnauthRolePolicy
    PolicyDocument: 
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement: 
        - 
          Effect: "Allow"
          Action: "execute-api:Invoke"
          Resource:
          - "arn:aws:execute-api:<region>:<account id>:<api id>/*/GET"/acc/dept/12/*"]]
  Roles: 
    - 
      Ref: UnauthRole
```

So based on above roles I have different access for my authenticated & unauthenticated users. Only caveat here is that your `identity pool id` must be a secret (i.e. not a good thing to expose in the browser).

Hope this helps.